# phpmyadmin not working chrome show error 500 firefox shows nothing

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, 16.04

im using ubuntu 16.04 LTS development branch. I have recently installed mysql, apache2 and phpmyadmin.
When i enter `localhost/phpmyadmin` in address bar in firefox it simply show nothing while chrome gives 500 server error.
When i see apache error.log it say

```
[Fri Jan 29 16:39:11.833839 2016] [:error] [pid 2795] [client 127.0.0.1:58438] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php//Crypt/Random.php' (include_path='.') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php on line 16
```

But `Random.php` exist in same location which error tells `failed opening`
Im Using

- ubuntu 16.04 development branch
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28,
- Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 5.6.17-3ubuntu1 (cli)

* *please ignore grammar mistakes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Random.php from the phpseclib has changed. I did a fast fix with changing:

```
$_SESSION[' PMA_token '] = bin2hex(phpseclib\Crypt\Random::string(16));
```

on line 116 and 135 with

```
$_SESSION[' PMA_token '] = bin2hex(crypt_random_string(16));
```

in the file **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php**

This should fix it for now until the phpmyadmin devs come with a solution.

**Edit 30-01-2016: The PMA devs fixed this. No need for changing the file manually.**

Answer (score 0):

user185719's answer helped me only partially, because the reported error persisted: **session.inc.php** was not able to include **Random.php**. Calling **file_exists()** on the **Random.php** always returnes false, while there are no permission issues, no **safe_mode**, so I don't really understand why this does not work as expected.
I had to do the following workaround to get phpmyadmin work (at least for now, until guys at phpmyadmin fix the problem):

- copy the following content of the file **/usr/share/php/Crypt/Random.php** into **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php**

  ```
  define('CRYPT_RANDOM_IS_WINDOWS', strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN');

  function crypt_random_string($length) {
      if (CRYPT_RANDOM_IS_WINDOWS) {
          ....
      }
  }
  ```

After copying the code above, user185719's answer should fix the issue. My system:

> Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
>   PHP 5.6.17-3
>   Apache 2.4.18
>   PhpMyadmin 4.5.4-1

Comment: You tested this on `mint?` can you back up the fact this will also work on Ubuntu? They are not the same.

Comment: Yes, this was tested on `Mint` only. I have **not** tested on `ubuntu`.

Comment: That is OK, just good to let people know, that comment should do fine, it may save some complaints and issuers down the line if it does not work on Ubuntu :)

Comment: The issue has been fixed in new package.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, phpmyadmin is not able to read Crypt/Random.php file, if placed in /usr/share/php folder. Moreover, I have tried also /usr/local/share/php5 with the same result. Finally I have copied whole Crypt folder from /usr/share/php into /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/

```
cp -r /usr/share/php/Crypt /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/
```

and modified /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/session.inc.php to include Crypt/Random.php from there.

```
#require PHPSECLIB_INC_DIR . '/Crypt/Random.php';
require ("/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Crypt/Random.php");
```

It worked, then I have got second error, described by jancoow. His fix helped me also to solve it (two places - line 117 and 136 in my case - creating session and destroying it).

So finally the question remains - why those files cannot be accessed from /usr/share/php or /usr/local/share/php5 folders? No need to add, that all access rights are OK.

My setup is

- Kubuntu 16.04 development
- phpmyadmin 4.5.4.-1
- apache2-bin 2.4.18-1ubuntu
- libapache2-mod-php5 5.6.16+dfsg-1ubuntu1